# How to turn on DPI scaling for just one monitor?

Tags: windows-8.1, display, scaling

I have two 1920x1080p monitors. One is kinda further away on a secondary desk though. I want to increase the display scaling on that monitor, so it's more readable from the distance I'm at. How can I do that without affecting my main monitor that is should just be set to 100% scaling (ie, no scaling)?

Comment: try the Win10 Preview. Some users reported, that it workes here.

Answer (score 0):

On my copy of Windows 8.1, I have a checkbox that says "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays" and it is unchecked. So you *can* change scaling per monitor. This is kind of mentioned in the duplicate post but that seems to dismiss it for some reason. It doesn't give you much control though as you still have to use the braindead slider.

However (and it is a biggie), behaviour is VERY inconsistent. Especially if, like me, you are constantly moving between different monitor configurations. However, with a single configuration, you may be OK.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you whether this is a feature that appeared in 8.1 update 1 or is a feature of the drivers on the Surface Pro 3.

Comment: Yea, I don't have this using a fully up to date Windows 8.1 Update 1 and Nvidia drivers. For me there is only ever 1 slider for both, and it's not per-monitor

Comment: Hmm, that must be down to the NVidia drivers then